# yaml.DEFAULT_SCHEMA.extend is not a function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, yaml, schema.yml

I am stuck with a lambda error `yaml.DEFAULT_SCHEMA.extend is not a function` while running the below code.

```
class CustomYamlTag {
    constructor(type, data) {
        this.type = type;
        this.data = data;
    }
}



//Lambda handler

exports.handler = event => {
    logger.info('Event', event);
    const SCHEMA = yaml.DEFAULT_SCHEMA.extend(tags);
    let TemplateBody = yaml.load(fs.readFileSync('templates/TEMPLATEFILE.yml', 'utf8'), { schema: SCHEMA });
....
```

I tried `const SCHEMA = yaml.Schema.extend(tags);` and ended up with the error
`yaml.Schema.extend is not a function`

Any suggestions on how to fix this or what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was thrown as I was using js-yaml 3.9.0.

I upgraded from js-yaml 3.9.0 to js-yaml 4.0.0 version and this allowed me to use `yaml.DEFAULT_SCHEMA.extend.`

extend property was added to the package on versions after 4.0.0

Reference

https://observablehq.com/@rmw4269/js-yaml